# How do I open the JSON response to my Twitter search query?

Tags: python, json, twitter, rauth

I have this rauth-powered command-line Python script so far:

```
import json
from rauth import OAuth1Service

twitter = OAuth1Service(
            name='twitter',
            consumer_key='[REDACTED]',
            consumer_secret='[REDACTED]',
            request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
            authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
            base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/')

request_token, request_token_secret = twitter.get_request_token()
authorize_url = twitter.get_authorize_url(request_token)

print 'Copy-paste this URL into your browser: ' + authorize_url
twitter_pin = raw_input('Enter PIN: ')

session = twitter.get_auth_session(request_token,
                                   request_token_secret,
                                   method='POST',
                                   data={'oauth_verifier': twitter_pin})

search_results = session.get('search/tweets.json', params={'q':'example'})

print json.dumps(search_results)
```

rauth does all the OAuth handling and I get an object in return. I try to print it and it says Response [200] (in pointy brackets), indicating a success. I try to use Python's json.dump to print out the contents and I get:

```
TypeError: <Response [200]> is not JSON serializable
```

I'm probably overlooking something very small. What's wrong with this?

[Relevant Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)
[Relevant rauth documentation](https://rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#oauth-1-0-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rauth` library builds on top of the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/), returning a specialised [`requests.Session` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects).

The object returned by [`session.get()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.get) is a [`requests.Response` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response); call the [`response.json()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) to get the JSON response data as a Python structure:

```
print search_results.json()
```

No need to dump that back into a JSON string, work directly with the Python data structure.